# WinRT ImageSource binding with cookies

Tags: data-binding, cookies, windows-runtime

I have a website and now I`m building a WinRT app for it. I use a JSON API both for web and for WinRT app.

One component is a picture gallery, where pictures have access control, so only specific users can download them.

Authorization is made using cookies, for WinRT they are held inside `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` object.

I tried to bind picture url`s as `ImageSource` for `Image` controls, but it fails because resource loader doesn`t send cookies to server.

I want to use binding because of it cleareness and simplicity, I don`t want to make complex code for such task as setting image inside a view.

**Questions:**

1. How can I bind `ImageSource` and force loader to send cookies to server when it tries to download a picture?
2. Is there a way to save simplicity of binding syntax and add custom loader behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with custom control with Source and HttpClient properties, which uses HttpClient to download picture and this client is shared across all app.